# Subtracting 2 lists

Tags: c#

I Have a syntax error using "Except".

```
var FirstList = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "New York",
                        "London",
                        "Mumbai",
                    };

            var SecondList = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "New York",
                        "London",
                        "Chicago"
                    };

            List<string> ThirdList = SecondList.Except(FirstList).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ThirdList));
```

I want the output result:

```
ThirdList = {"Mumbai"}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just add a `using System.Linq` line at the top

Comment: If the code is working, you can simplify it somewhat.  The `String.Join` function takes an IEnumerable, it doesn't require a string.  Declare `ThirdList` with `var` (i.e., `var thirdList = ...`) and then get rid of the call to `ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

Word of advice put your cursor at the wrong syntax and press `ctrl` + `.` first and you will see that
you are missing

```
using System.Linq;
```

and I think you are getting this wrong what will happen is that the linq command will remove any entry that is in `FirstList` from `SecondList` so you will get `"Chicago"` instead, if you want `ThirdList = {"Mumbai"}` you need to reverse

```
var ThirdList = FirstList.Except(SecondList);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ThirdList));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need 2 changes

1. Add namespace using `System.Linq`; Your error will be removed.
2. Since you need Mumbai as result therefore your code will be like below

```
List<string> ThirdList = FirstList.Except(SecondList).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ThirdList));
```